# Can I pass parameters to a CDP (connect direct) file?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, mainframe

I am using Connect Direct to transfer some data from a DAT file to Mainframe. I would like to be able to specify what environment we pull from based on a parameter passed to the CDP file instead of having to create a CDP to pull from each environment.  Right now my CDP file looks something like this:

```
/*BEGIN_REQUESTER_COMMENTS 
    $PNODE$="NT.STUFFHERE.P" $PNODE_OS$="Windows NT" 
    $SNODE$="CD2.SOMETHING" $SNODE_OS$="MVS" 
    $OPTIONS$="" 
  END_REQUESTER_COMMENTS*/

    URSOUT PROCESS 
    SNODE=CD2.SOMETHING
    CLASS=1
    PRTY=10
    RETAIN=No
    HOLD=No
    SNODEID=(S2243CD,S2243CD)

    STEP01 COPY 
    FROM (
        FILE=\\**[Dev server alias]**\mis_shr\MIS\data\upload\urs_feed_sort.dat
    )
    TO (
        FILE=[Mainframe address]
    DISP=(RPL,KEEP,DELETE)
    DCB=(BLKSIZE=6800,DSORG=ps,LRECL=680,RECFM=fb)
        SPACE=(CYL,(052,020),RLSE)
       )

    STEP02 IF (STEP01 GT 4) THEN

    EXIT 

EIF 


PEND
```

This CDP file is being called by a BAT file containing:

```
submit file=d:\bond_cd\FB\cdp\FB_URS_prem_feed_out.cdp
quit;
```

What I would really like to be able to do is to change that [Dev server alias] based on some argument. I would like to use this same CDP file for my different DEV and TEST environments. How would I do this? I know I would have to create some sort of $env variable and then set that to certain strings based on this parameter. I'm not sure if this is possible though.

Maybe something like this when I call the CDP file:

```
submit file=d:\bnd\FB\cdp\FB_URS_prem_feed_out.cdp DEV
quit;
```

and

```
submit file=d:\bond_cd\FB\cdp\FB_URS_prem_feed_out.cdp TEST
quit;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use your application to create a yyy.txt file dynamically. In the yyy.txt file, add the parameters like this:

submit file=C:\xxx\xxx.cdp NEWNAME=xxxxx PNode=xxx2 &Fname=xxxx.dat &Directory=xxx &Snode=xxx &env=qa maxdelay=unlimited;select process;quit;

In the bat file, run the yyy.txt:

cd C:\Program Files\Sterling Commerce\Connect Direct v4.4.00\Common Utilities\ 
direct.exe -fd:/apps/xxx/xxx/xxx.bin < C:/xxx/yyy.txt